# Alternative to DirectorySlash Off

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm stuck, my hosting provider uses a fork of Apache HTTPD server that supports mod_rewrite and `<Location>` (as `:Location`), but it does not support `DirectorySlash` option.

Is there any way I can implement it using mod_rewrite? In other words, is there any way I can prevent Apache from redirecting clients to urls with trailing slash when a folder exists if a requested name. Maybe there's a way to force the server to parse RewriteRules before doing a redirect?

All I want is to be able to request files that have the same name as folders but with clean urls (no extension).

Comment: Hm, if you can disable the entire `mod_dir` perhaps (which has its drawbacks...). Which fork are we talking about, is there information online about it or it his their own custom build?

Comment: Actually trailing slash is added in front of directories only when `mod_dir` is enabled and `DirectorySlash On` is set. Without `mod_dir` trailing slash won't be added at all.

Comment: @Wrikken I don't think it's a publicly known fork of any sorts. It's called IdeaWebServer. I couldn't find any documentation for it other than it supports Apache's `mod_rewrite`. I am not able to disable `mod_dir`, unless it's doable from `.htaccess`?